# javascript won't change dom value

Tags: javascript, dom

I have no  idea what i doing wrong.
I dynamically insert rows to table. These rows have some cells, in cells I have input elements.
Next i change values in input via browser (just type in filed :) ).
When i get element by id of this_table values of input fields are default.

```js
var testbtn=document.getElementById('test');
testbtn.onclick = function(){
var tab=document.getElementById('testtab');
var row = tab.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.className='th_lp';
    cell1.innerHTML='<input id="testid" value="1"></input>';
    cell1.className='th_lp';
    cell2.innerHTML='bb';
}
var testbtn2=document.getElementById('test2');
test2.onclick=function(){
 alert(document.getElementById('testtab').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table id="testtab" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>th1</th><th>th2</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="test">
TEST
</button>
<br>
<button id="test2">
TEST2
</button>
```

Here is simple example

<kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ah8pv3ff/2/)</kbd>

1. click btn
2. change input text to some else
3. click btn

when I do these steps i have alert message
"......"
input value is still 1. Why?

How can I get innerHTML of this table with new input values?

Comment: Why didn't you make the `jsfiddle.net/ah8pv3ff/2/`  clickable? Did you see a warning that you should not only link to `jsfiddle` but also include the code with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user changes the value of an input field, then the property `value`  is changed but not the attribute. `innerHTML` does show the content of the  attribute `value` but not the property `value`. You would need to manually *sync*  the attributes before calling `innerHTML`

You could do something like that:

```js
var testbtn = document.getElementById('test');
testbtn.onclick = function() {
  var tab = document.getElementById('testtab');
  var row = tab.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.className = 'th_lp';
  cell1.innerHTML = '<input id="testid" value="1">';
  cell1.className = 'th_lp';
  cell2.innerHTML = 'bb';
}
var testbtn2 = document.getElementById('test2');
test2.onclick = function() {
  
  //search for all input elements
  var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  
  for( var i=0; i < inputElements.length ; i++ ) {
    //set the attribute value of the input element to the content of the property value
    inputElements[i].setAttribute('value',inputElements[i].value );
  }
  
  alert(document.getElementById('testtab').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table id="testtab" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>th1</th>
    <th>th2</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="test">
  TEST
</button>
<br>
<button id="test2">
  TEST2
</button>
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus thats true, I didn't review all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute of the input will never change unless you set it manually.  Think of this as the "default" value (used primarily with form.reset).  You are going to have to add an onblur/onkeyup event to update the value if you want the HTML to dynamically reflect the value.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you add a new input element, it gets the same id as the last one. ID's should be unique. Also, input is not a content element. It should not have a closing tag.

Comment: Yes you wrigth, but this is small simple example, in final i don't use id's i use calsses only ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before I fully looked at what this is about, I see cell1.className blah TWICE, while I see no such thing for cell2... is that why i get an error?

Comment: Yes, i copy and paste, but in my full code i have 64 cells, and there I don't have TWICE any cells.

Answer (score 0):

In your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ah8pv3ff/2/), if you change:

```
alert(document.getElementById('testtab').innerHTML);
```

to:

```
alert(document.getElementById('testid').value);
```

you will see that the input's value matches what you entered.

Comment: Yes. I know that, but i need html code for full page, not only this one input.

Comment: @TomaszKujawa Why do you need the html code? What's your goal?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute’s main role is to initialize the DOM properties. So, once the DOM initialization completed, the attribute's job is done.

In general, property values can change, whereas the attribute values can never be changed.

Replace

```
document.getElementById('testtab').innerHTML;
```

with

```
document.getElementById('testid').value;
```